# Why 0.1 is sometimes printed exactly and sometimes not?

Tags: python, floating-point

I run:

```
print(0.1)
print(0.2)
print(0.3)
print(0.4)
print(0.5)
print(0.5-0.4)
print(0.4-0.3)
print(0.3-0.2)
print(0.2-0.1)
```

It shows:

```
0.1
0.2
0.3
0.4
0.5
0.09999999999999998
0.10000000000000003
0.09999999999999998
0.1
```

Why print number directly is fine, but use of the operator `-` will get unexpected value?

I have checked:
[Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

If `0.5-0.4` could not be saved in hardware precisely, why just print(0.1) will show 0.1 not 0.10000000000xxx?

Maybe more clear statement is:

In my understanding, python should print(0.1) to be 0.10000000000xxx, and 0.5-0.4 should equal to 0.4-0.3 and equal to 0.3-0.2, right?

Why python could "Python keeps the number of digits manageable by displaying a rounded value"? If python wants to print(0.1) to be 0.1, it should treat 0.4-0.3 as 0.1 well, right? Why python want us to be confusion on this kind of topics?

For even more precise statement that this problem is "not" really argue that 0.5-0.4 != 0.4-0.3. My main problem is print(0.1)= 0.1 not 0.10000000000xxxx, why python could do this kind of action? It will let us very confusion with the "Is floating point math broken?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because *the numbers are not equal*. Consider the following, when you pass a `float` directly to `Decimal` to get a better representation of what is going on:

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> Decimal(0.1)
Decimal('0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625')
>>> Decimal(0.5 - 0.4)
Decimal('0.09999999999999997779553950749686919152736663818359375')
```

Notice, that the actual floating point value you get from the literal `0.1` is different than the result of the subtraction of floats that are created from the literals `0.5` and `0.4`. This is because the two literals *also can have an error* (note, `0.5` can be represented exactly, because it can be expressed as a power of two).

```
>>> Decimal(0.5)
Decimal('0.5')
>>> Decimal(0.4)
Decimal('0.40000000000000002220446049250313080847263336181640625')
```

Note, the *string* python prints when you print a number is *even more of an approximation*, although Python uses an algorithm which should produce the shortest representation that can reliably reproduce the actual floating point value from the literal:

```
>>> 0.5 - 0.4
0.09999999999999998
>>> Decimal(0.09999999999999998)
Decimal('0.09999999999999997779553950749686919152736663818359375')
>>> Decimal(0.5 - 0.4)
Decimal('0.09999999999999997779553950749686919152736663818359375')
```

Note, pretty much any language I can think of uses a truncated form of the floating point number that is actually represented in hardware. If you want to see more, you generally have to use string formatting.

Comment: Is your answer related to why print(0.1) is 0.1 not 0.1000000000000xxx? If yes, how they related with? Thanks.

Comment: @sam please re-read

Comment: @sam the representation you see from `print(x)` does not reflect the floating point value

Comment: I think your answer precisely described 0.5-0.4 is not equal to 0.4-0.3, 0.3-0.2, because 0.4, 0.3 numbers also have an error,right? However, I think print(0.1) should print 0.1000000000xxx or 0.999999999xxx, why print(0.1)'s 0.1 should not be effect with hardware?

Comment: @sam **because `print` is lying to you** for the sake of aesthetics

Comment: @sam the string representation that is printed is the *shortest one that reliably reproduces the actual float* (although that is a CPython implementation detail, as long as it is reliable, it doesn't have to be the shortest I don't think)

Comment: I do not accept python could do such "aesthetics", because 0.1 is calculated with 0.5-0.4,right?

Comment: @sam **no** no it isn't. What do you not understand about `0.1 != 0.5 - 0.4`?

Comment: @sam again, all languages lie to you in this sense.

Comment: I'll just add that `0.1 == 0.2 - 0.1` is actually `True`. While neither `0.1` nor `0.2` can be represented exactly, `0.2` is represented exactly as 2 times as much as `0.1`. It's because these two numbers have the same mantissa and only differ by exponent. That's why this specific subtraction behaves differently than the other ones.

Comment: Let me try to summary  
@juanpa.arrivillaga answer: Due to python's "aesthetics", python print(0.1)=0.1 only on the situation of visualization, but when calculation, python will let 0.1 saved as 0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625, and 0.4, 0.3 also have its own error, so the - operation will cause all the comparison to be not equal,right?

Comment: I found that what I really confused is if python use use "aesthetics" to show 0.1, why python couldn't use "aesthetics" to show 0.4-0.3 also 0.1?

Comment: @sam I've explained it multiple times, because it uses *the shortest representation that will reliably reproduce the actual value*

Comment: @sam: It's partly a consequence of two design decisions in Python 3: first, that the `repr` of a float should be "faithful" (that is, different floats should have different `repr`s), and second, that the `str` and `repr` of a `float` should be identical. It follows from those choices that if two (non-NaN) floats do not compare equal then they'll `print` differently. Note that Python 2 made different choices, and in Python 2, `print(0.5 - 0.4)` _will_ give the same output as `print(0.1)`, despite that the two values being printed are not equal to one another.

Comment: `repr` being faithful is important because it's a precondition for being able to reconstruct a float from its `repr` (e.g., via `eval` or the `float` constructor).

Comment: That would be interesting to understand what's exactly behind the `Decimal` module because 0.1 in the IEEE double-precision format should be I believe Sum[2^(-4*i) + 2^(-4*i - 1), {i, 1, 12}] which is approximated as 0.09999999999999964472863211994990706 with 35 digits of accuracy. This number disagress with the one indicated above. I am not sure why.

Comment: @pluton I don't think so. It's just the same number I would get if I create a little C program to do : `printf("%.55f\n", (double) 0.1);` which gives me `0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga If I apply the IEEE double-precision binary format as I know it (the basic definition), I get (0.1)decimal = (1.1001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011010)binary * 2^(-4)) where I use rounding up on the last entry 53) and the number is 3602879701896397/36028797018963968 which can be approximated as 0.10000000000000000555111512312578270 which is the one you show. Good! There was an issue in my initial attempt.